# crystal report not displayed some fields from query

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

my query :

```
 SqlDataAdapter daaa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT inq.InquiryId,inq.Inquiry_Date,inq.Factor_Code,inq.CustomerName,"+
      "inq.TermsPayment,inq.DeliveryTime,trd.TrCellType from inquiry AS inq  LEFT JOIN inquiryjoin " +
      "ON inq.InquiryId = inquiryjoin.InquiryId " +
      " LEFT JOIN traditional AS trd " +
      "ON trd.TraditionalId = inquiryjoin.TId " +
      " LEFT JOIN compact " +
      "ON compact.CompactId = inquiryjoin.TId " +
      " LEFT JOIN air " +
      "ON air.AirId = inquiryjoin.TId where " +
      "inq.Inquiry_Date = N'" + stdate + "' " +
      " ORDER BY inq.InquiryId", Conn);
```

(trd.TrCellType) not show in report ?

Comment: Have you ever test your query in your database? Did you see all the fields there?

Comment: did you have trd.celltype in xml dataset or did you given any formula in report

Comment: Yes, I tested with Sql server and was correct

Comment: with dataset added to crystal report no formula in report

Answer (score 0):

First run this code in sqlserver, I think you don't have data in table with this condition in left join of table "**LEFT JOIN traditional AS trd**"

First get the proper result at sqlserver side, if there is ok, then definately crystal report shows data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT inq.inquiryid,
            inq.inquiry_date,
            inq.factor_code,
            inq.customername,
            inq.termspayment,
            inq.deliverytime,
            trd.trcelltype FROM   inquiry AS inq
   LEFT JOIN inquiryjoin
          ON inq.inquiryid = inquiryjoin.inquiryid
   LEFT JOIN traditional AS trd
          ON trd.traditionalid = inquiryjoin.tid
   LEFT JOIN compact
          ON compact.compactid = inquiryjoin.tid
   LEFT JOIN air
          ON air.airid = inquiryjoin.tid
```

WHERE  inq.inquiry_date = N'2013/01/01'
ORDER  BY inq.inquiryid

Comment: (trd.trcelltype) does not show in report ! please say to me if i most done anything else in the crystal reports ?